# Create an RSS feed for any webpage, monitor changes and send results by email?

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, rss, yahoo-pipes

Do you know a Windows 7 software (not an online service like yahoo pipes. As if, for instance, such company goes bankrupt I lose everything!) than can create an RSS feed for any webpage ? Here is what I am looking for : 
I manually select what is a title, what is a link and if needed what is the content that I would like to keep (article content + their related images if they exist). The software create a RSS feed from that. 
Then it monitors the feed every x hours (or x days at a specified time). If updates are found then send the results to my email address.

Note : It is a little like a combination of the Firefox addon: [Autopager](https://addons.mozilla.org/eN/firefox/addon/autopager/) (WYSIWYG selection which uses xpath) and [WebSite-Watcher](http://www.aignes.com/) (RSS software monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the highly extensible, Awasu: http://www.awasu.com/.

The WebScrape Channel Plugin http://www.awasu.com/wiki/WebScrape_Plugin_Channel can scrape portions of a web page to serve as the feed item's title, descriptive text and link.

There's a SendEmail Channel Hook that you can attach to any feed (normal RSS or from a Channel Plugin like WebScrape); the SendEmail Channel Hook will send an email when new feed items are found.

This just barely scratches the surface of what Awasu can do, but it specifically solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. But it uses "regular expressions". This is not enough easy for me. ;( I would much prefer something like Autopager (one click and I select what I want. I copy the xpath and I am done ! ).